# How could I make a div "slide" to a certain width using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, scale, slide

I have a div that scales to an image width + height using jquery. I want to know if I can make it "slide" to the width and height.

So instead of just instantly scaling to those dimensions, I want a nice transaction slide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#div').animate({width:500+'px', height:500+'px'});
```

Replace 500 with your dimensions

Answer (score 0):

You could use "show" ?

```
$("yourSelector").show("slow");
```

see: http://api.jquery.com/show/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you want to animate it. In addition to .animate, and .show, there is also

> $("div").slideUp();

see: http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/

> $("div").slideDown("slow");

see: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('div').animate({'width': '+= 50'});
```

that may work